# Problems installing older versions of odbc in R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, dbi

I'm trying to troubleshoot why my colleague can pull down 1.6M rows of data from a Snowflake table using odbc in less than 1 min whereas it take over an hour for me to do the same.

The only difference I can see in the sessionInfo is that I'm using odbc 1.3.4 and he's using 1.3.3

I wish to install 1.3.3 but I get the following errors:

```
install_version("odbc", version = "1.3.3")
Downloading package from url: https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/odbc/odbc_1.3.3.tar.gz
* installing *source* package 'odbc' ...
** package 'odbc' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
(cd cctz && \
/usr/bin/make libcctz.a PREFIX="../" CC=""C:/Program Files/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc " CXX=""C:/Program Files/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++11" AR=""C:/Program Files/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"ar" ARFLAGS=rv)
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6pjx3A/remotes493859cb6bfe/odbc/src-i386/cctz'
C:/Program  -Wall -Iinclude -std=c++11 -pthread  -O  -MMD  -c -o time_zone_format.o src/time_zone_format.cc
make[1]: C:/Program: Command not found
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: time_zone_format.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6pjx3A/remotes493859cb6bfe/odbc/src-i386/cctz'
make: *** [Makevars.win:13: cctz/libcctz.a] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'odbc'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/odbc'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6pjx3A/remotes493859cb6bfe/odbc’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can someone help me decipher what could be causing this issue? I've been troubleshooting this for 1.5 days now and I am no closer to an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There could be a lot more factors than just the odbc version, but one notable improvement from odbc 1.3.4 seems to be performance related as documented [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/pull/525). Can you try: `install.packages("odbc",version = "1.3.3")` and choose "NO" when asked if compiled from source?

Comment: For the "compile" problem, there is definitely something wrong with your Rtools setup, but it isn't clear if you edited the text in your question or if it really is that messed up. For instance, `CC=""C:/Program Files/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc "` is wrong in every way, and `C:/Program  -Wall -Iinclude` appears to be missing the compiler itself. Peculiar to R and Rtools, I always recommend against installing either into `c:/Program Files/`, as many R utilities do poorly with paths with spaces in them. I suggest you install them into `c:/R/R-4.3.2/` and `c:/rtools42/`, respectively.

Comment: @Sergiu thanks for the reply. I've run your code above and it installed 1.3.4 and I wasn't prompted whether to compile from source or not.

Comment: @r2evans the only edit I made to the output was to change my name to "me". Unfortunately this is on a work laptop where I have no control over where the install happens, I select to install R from a website and it installs on my laptop, there's no input from my end. Even installing 1.3.4 I have a very slow read time from Snowflake, are there some additional parameters I can pass i.e. batch or fetch sizes to speed up the performance?

Comment: That compile command is really broken. If you want to try downgrading again, use Posit's https://packagemanager.rstudio.com for a binary package. As for download speed, `odbc` can only do as much as the underlying ODBC (OS-level) package is configured to do. I suggest you compare your ODBC driver (version, configuration) with your colleagues.